# CSV parsing, newline/linebreak issues

Tags: ruby, excel, csv

I'm trying to create a parser for multiple CSV files, that will eventually output to another CSV file in Excel-compatible format.  The CSV files are exported by a commercial tool that takes a Firewall configuration and gives us a report of any issues it finds.

So far I have figured out how to read a directory of files in, look for certain values, determine the type of device I have and then spit it out to screen or to a CSV, but only if each line has single cell entries. If the source IP 'cell' (or any other) contains more than one IP, separated by a newline, the output breaks on that newline and pushes the remainder onto the next line.

The code I have so far is:

```
require 'csv'
require 'pp'

nipperfiles = Dir.glob(ARGV[0] + '/*.csv')

def allcsv(nipperfiles)
  filearray = []
  nipperfiles.each do |csv|
    filearray << csv
  end

  filearray
end

def devicetype(filelist)
  filelist.each do |f|
    CSV.foreach(f, :headers => true, :force_quotes => true) do |row|
      if row["Table"] =~ /audit device list/ && row["Device"] =~ /Cisco/
        return "Cisco"
      elsif row["Table"] =~ /audit device list/ && row["Device"] =~ /Dell/
        return "Sonicwall"
      elsif row["Table"] =~ /audit device list/ && row["Device"] =~ /Juniper/
        return "Juniper"
      end
    end
  end
end

def adminservices(device, filelist)
  administrative = []

  filelist.each do |f|
    CSV.foreach(f, :headers => true, :col_sep => ",", :force_quotes => true, :encoding => Encoding::UTF_8) do |row|
      if row["Table"] =~ /administrative service rule/
        if row["Dst Port"] != "Any" and row["Service"] != "[Host] Any"
          if device == "Cisco"
            administrative << row["Table"] + ',' + row["Rule"] + ',' + row["Protocol"] + ',' + row["Source"] + ',' + row["Destination"] + ',' + row["Dst Port"]
          elsif device == "Sonicwall"
            administrative << row["Table"] + ',' + row["Rule"] + ',' + row["Source"] + ',' + row["Destination"] + ',' + row["Service"]
          elsif device == "Juniper"            
            administrative << row["Table"] + ',' + row["Rule"] + ',' + row["Source"] + ',' + row["Destination"] + ',' + row["Service"]
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
  administrative
end

def writecsv(admin)

  finalcsv = File.new("randomstorm.csv", "w+")
  finalcsv.puts("Administrative Services Table:\n", admin, "\r\n")
  finalcsv.close

end

filelist = allcsv(nipperfiles)
device = devicetype(filelist)
adminservices(device, filelist)
admin = adminservices(device, filelist)
writecsv(admin)
```

Is there a way to get it to ignore the newlines that are inside cells, or is my code complete balls and needs to be started again?

I have tried writing a CSV file with the CSV library, but the results are the same and I figured this code was slightly clearer for demonstrating the issue.

I can sanitise an input file if it would help.

Comment: Share couple of examples of problematic lines from input file

Comment: Welcome. Please don't use valedictions ("Many thanks,") or signatures ("Rich"). We're writing a reference book, not having a discussion, so you're writing the first part of an article about how to solve the problem you're asking about. Also, is your code the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem? Please read "[mcve]" and "[ask]".

Comment: Please supply minimal input data that works with your code and demonstrates the problem. Expecting us to imagine the data doesn't work well. Use the CSV class extensively. CSV isn't a well-adhered-to format and the class has been tested very well so it will handle situations you haven't encountered or imagined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

newlines are OK inside of fields as long they are quoted:

```
CSV.parse("1,\"2\n\n\",3")
=> [["1", "2\n\n", "3"]]
```

Try writing directly to a string or a file like in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-Writing) which will ensure your fields with newlines are quoted:

```
def writecsv(admin)
 csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
   admin.each { |row| csv << row }
 end 

 finalcsv = File.new("randomstorm.csv", "w+")
 finalcsv.puts("Administrative Services Table:\n", csv_string, "\r\n")
 finalcsv.close
end
```

Also ensure you are writing your fields as an array inside of `adminservices()`:

```
administrative << [row["Table"], row["Rule"], row["Protocol"], row["Source"], row["Destination"], row["Dst Port"]]
```

Comment: Martin,
Thank you so much for the response! That works absolutely perfectly. I have been banging my head against this brick wall for days now. You have saved my sanity.

Comment: It's idiomatic Ruby to use the block form of `File.open` rather than use `File.new`.